# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. creating node js apps

Tags: node.js

I'm using cordova to create apps and when I used the command
`cordova build android` I got this error through the CLI:

> c:\Apps\projeto_1>cordova build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

> Starting Daemon
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 75
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 29.0.3; minimum version required is 30.0.3.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: c:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\build.gradle

Example of build failure: *Build failed with an exception.*

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 75
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 30.x installed version is 29.0.3; minimum version required is 30.0.3.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: c:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\Apps\projeto_1\platforms\android\build.gradle

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on SO should be phrased in English..

Comment: hello sorry, i'll pass this question on to english...

Comment: please i need a lot of help i've been studying programming for a very short time and i'm mostly lost in the tools i just need to know how to update or a command in the CMD that updates for me...
I don't know much about the rules here.

Comment: _"I don't know much about the rules here."_ Then start to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to read up upon what makes a good question here on SO..